# Help with appropriate parametrisation

Tags: surfaces

> Let $S$ be the surface $x^2+2y^2+z^2=1$.
>
> Find a parameterisation of $S$ and use it to find the equation of the tangent plane to $S$ at the point $\left(\frac1{\sqrt2},\frac12,0\right)$.

I can't work out an equation of tangent plane using parametrization onto polar coordinates. Is there any way to solve the question?

Comment: Polar coordinates? If my guess on what you tried to do is right, there's a small scaling to make that work. Can you show us your parametrization?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If

$$
x = x(\theta,\phi),\
y = y(\theta,\phi),\
z = z(\theta,\phi)\
$$

is your parametrization (which I assume is spherical coordinates, not polar), then the cross product of

$$
(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta})
$$

and

$$
(\frac{\partial x}{\partial \phi}, \frac{\partial y}{\partial \phi}, \frac{\partial z}{\partial \phi})
$$

is normal to the surface.